# Connect reset by peer with Golang http server on Mac OS10.9.5

Tags: macos, go

I got an weird error when writing some stress tests on a golang web application.
Here is the code for web server

```
package httptest

import (
    "net/http"
    "testing"
)

func TestHttpTest(t *testing.T) {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        //<-time.After(2 * time.Second)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":2222", nil)
}
```

When I run go test ./... and use ApacheBench to perform stress test:

```
ab -c 200 -n 1000 http://localhost:2222/123
```

It gives me following error randomly:

```
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/
Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 235 requests completed
```

I am running the test on Mac OS 10.9. The ulimit of the os is setting as unlimited. Does anyone meet the same problem?

Comment: You've probably run out of ports, or hit an older bug in `ab`. OSX's network stack is not very well optimized for this sort of thing. Also; `ab` is not a reliable benchmark tool, and benchmarking network servers over loopback is mostly useless

Comment: while the test is running check the output of netstat ?